# No figure and references in Applied Physics Express LaTex file?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I am preparing a manuscript in LaTeX for the journal of Applied Physics Express, class `jjap3.cls`. But I cannot get any references and figures in the manuscript. Here is the website I downloaded the LaTeX files for this journal https://journals.jsap.jp/apex/authors/downloads.

The `.tex` file is:

```
\documentclass{jjap3}
%%% Either of the following options can provide the similar output with the version of record.
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{txfonts}
%%%
%%% If you use BibTeX for references, the following lines should be live.
%\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage{doi}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
%%% or %%%
%\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}



\title{This is an example}


\author{xxx$^{1,2}$ \thanks{E-mail: xxx@hotmail.com}, xxx$^{1}$, and xxx$^{1,2}$}


\inst{$^{1}$xxxx University, USA \\ 
$^{2}$xxxxx University, USA}



\abst{This Letter theoretically demonstrates that xxxxxxx.}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Tilted fiber Bragg grating (TFBG) presents many unique spectral characteristics \cite{Albert2013}.



\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3in]{fig_sensor}
    \caption{Diagram structure of TFBG.}
    \label{fig-sensor}
\end{figure}



\bibliography{reference}


\end{document}
```

Also, the `.bib` file is:

```
@article{Albert2013,
  title={Tilted fiber Bragg grating sensors},
  author={Albert, Jacques and Shao, Li-Yang and Caucheteur, Christophe},
  journal={Laser Photonics Rev.},
  volume={7},
  number={1},
  pages={83-108},
  year={2013},
  month={Feb},
  doi={10.1002/lpor.201100039 },
}
```

After compiling, there are no references and figures in the manuscript.

Is there anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can compile the following MWE with `xelatex` after changing the extention of the image to `.eps` and uncommenting `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}`:

```
\documentclass{jjap3}
%%% Either of the following options can provide the similar output with the version of record.
%\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{txfonts}
%%%
%%% If you use BibTeX for references, the following lines should be live.
%\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage{doi}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1} % <=======================================
%%% or %%%
%\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}

\title{This is an example}

\author{xxx$^{1,2}$ \thanks{E-mail: xxx@hotmail.com}, xxx$^{1}$, and xxx$^{1,2}$}

\inst{$^{1}$xxxx University, USA \\ 
$^{2}$xxxxx University, USA

\abst{This Letter theoretically demonstrates that xxxxxxx.}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Tilted fiber Bragg grating (TFBG) presents many unique spectral characteristics \cite{Albert2013}.
Link to figure~\ref{fig-sensor}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image.eps} % fig_sensor <=========
    \caption{Diagram structure of TFBG.}
    \label{fig-sensor}
\end{figure}

\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

That results in the following MWE:

[image]

The problem with the figure results from the using of option `dvipdfmx` in class `jjap3.cls` for calling package `graphicx`:

```
\RequirePackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
```